# Having problems running a batch script from windows shell command

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm in over my head. This is for my company who just laid off everyone that used to do this.

Quick summary: I have modified the registry so when you right click a folder, you get the option "Folder_To_PDF" and the data for the regedit is merge1.bat "%1" which runs a batch file that is located in C:\Windows

Problem: Click on "Folder to PDF" and it appears the cmd.exe opens for a brief second, then disappears but never actually executes. (It is supposed to open Ghostscript then do the folder to PDF)

What I've done: I have successfully made the batch file work by moving it from C:\Windows to the folder itself, where you can run the batch file and it opens Ghostscript fine. So I know it's not the batch file or Ghostscript setup. I think the problem is either 1) this is a corporate computer with corporate security, maybe not allowing it to run as admin? (I am an Admin by sheer lack of options) Or, the folder to pdf button does not know where to find the batch file, but I've already created a PATH in the environment variables.

Comment: Add a `pause` at various points in the script and remark out any `cls` and `@echo off` commands to try to see where the script fails.

Comment: It might not even be executing the batch file. Try putting a fully-qualified path to merge1.bat. Relying on the %path% is fragile as you might execute the wrong one without knowing. Check also that the command that the batch file is running is also accessible. If it's running an exe, is there an assumption that that exe is also in the path.